jar file is not generated in my spring project
I am learning Spring and I have already completed a project. Now I want to upload it to the internet and publish it in my portfolio. However, when I give the following command in cmd: mvn clean package, I get the image error.

Something I'm also going to share with you is my pom.xml and my application.properties. I've been trying to solve this problem for 2 days now but I can't find the solution. I hope you can help me.
pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.projetspring.meriem</groupId>
    <artifactId>projet-spring-react</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ecommerce-backend</name>
    <description>projet spring react</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Configuración del plugin de compilación de Maven -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.10.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

application.properties
# Configuración de tamaño de archivos
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=500KB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=500KB

# Configuración de la base de datos para Azure
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://databasenavarra.mysql.database.azure.com:3306/ecommerce_navarra_spring?serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=adminuserdb@databasenavarra
spring.datasource.password=Xxchalo24397xX
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

# Configuración de JPA e Hibernate
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect


.properties are irrelevant, the are read at runtime, this is a build time error

First you should upgrade the spring boot verison you are using because spring boot version 2.7.0 is end of support (https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot#support) current versions are 3.3.2 ... also overwirte the plugin version of maven-resources-plugin with the most recent version (3.3.1 https://maven.apache.org/plugins/) furthermore check the content of the spring-react part if your resources are correctly encoded in UTF-8 ???

My guess is this is the issue:
 <!-- Configuración del plugin de compilación de Maven -->
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.10.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>11</source>
        <target>11</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>

Delete it, and it will work. In general, you shouldn't adjust build unless you know what you are doing, and just let spring-boot-maven-plugin do its work

Try to use the following command mvn clean at the root folder of the project (the folder where you save all files of your project).
If you use netbeans, only click on clean and build button while the maven project is open.

The clean will not help here... it's failuing during the resource copying...
